# Does this prove that $y={1\over x}$ has no midpoint?

Tags: limits, proof-verification, improper-integrals

I was looking at the area under $y={1\over x}$, and randomly I wondered if there was some point at which the areas on either side were equal.

I set about finding the answer using this method:
$$\\
\lim_{a\to0^+} {\int_a^p{dx\over x}}=\lim_{b\to\infty} {\int_p^b{dx\over x}}\\
\lim_{a\to0^+}\ln p - \ln a=\lim_{b\to\infty}\ln b - \ln p\\
2\ln p=\lim_{a\to0^+}\ln a+\lim_{b\to\infty} \ln b\\
2\ln p = -\infty+\infty\\
$$
Upon seeing the last line, I concluded that given the indeterminate form, $p\in(0,\infty)$, which I interpreted to mean "$p$ does not exist"

Is this rigorous enough, or did I skip some steps?

Comment: "On either side" of what?  Depending on what you mean by "area," an answer like $x=\pm 1$ might be acceptable.

Comment: Well both of your initial integrals diverge, i.e. have infinite area under them, for any p. Since both integrals are not really defined you may want to try this with a different function so that both integrals converge

Comment: since the improper integrals are not convergent， how you define the “area”？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $\lim_{a\to0^+} {\int_a^p{dx\over x}}$ diverges and $\lim_{b\to\infty} {\int_p^b{dx\over x}}$ diverges too. So, since these two areas tend to $\infty$, you cannot compare those two. Hence you cannot find a point where these two areas are equal.

From the indeterminate that you found you cannot conclude the non-existence of $p$ cause an indeterminate form of $\infty -\infty$ with some manipulations can lead to a number or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement that $p$ does not exist is correct.

You know that the total integral is $\infty$ and you are looking for a point which divides infinity in two equal parts.

Now if the point $p$  is a real point,then the first half of the integral will be bounded and can not be infinity.

Thus even without integration we notice that such a point does not exist.

The same argument goes for every integral which diverges to infinity.